# Qt::QAbstractItemModel::beginRemoveRows() crash

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a problem with implementation of custom model (base class is `QAbstractItemModel`) for `QTreeView`.

In a nutshell, after calling of `beginRemoveRows()`, `QAbstractItemModel` calls my implementation of `parent()` with `QModelIndex` that returns dangling pointer from `QModelIndex::internalPointer()`. Here is call stack:
[image: Call stack]

Ok, posting as small part of code as possible..

I'm working with next tree:

[image: Tree view]

Here are solutions that contain projects that contain files.

---

**Model contains instances of `FileItem` class:**

```
class FileItem;
typedef QSharedPointer<FileItem> FileItemPtr;

class FileItem
{
public:
    explicit FileItem(File* file, FileItem* parentItem = nullptr);
    ...
    FileItem* child(int row); // returns @row element of @childItems_ vector
    FileItem* parentItem() const; // returns @parentItem_
    void removeChild(int row); // removes @row element from @childItems_ vector

private:
    QVector<FileItemPtr> childItems_;
    FileItem* parentItem_;
    ...
};
```

---

**Here is model's (`FilesModel`) main functions:**

```
class FilesModel :
    public QAbstractItemModel
{
    ...
private:
    QModelIndex index(
        int row,
        int column = 0,
        const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex& index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    // returns corresponding childCount() for valid @parent's internalPointer()
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        return 1;
    }

private:
    QVector<FileItemPtr> items_;
}
```

---

**`QModelIndex`'s creation:**

```
QModelIndex FilesModel::index(
    int row,
    int column /*= 0*/,
    const QModelIndex& parent /*= QModelIndex()*/) const
{
    if(!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return invalidIndex();

    if(!parent.isValid()) // If, parent is invalid, then @row is our items_[row]
    {
        if(row < items_.size())
        {
            FileItem* item = items_.value(row).data();
            // Pass @item as QModelIndex's internal pointer
            return createIndex(row, column, item);
        }
        return invalidIndex();
    }

    FileItem* parentItem = static_cast<FileItem*>(parent.internalPointer());
    FileItem* childItem = parentItem->child(row);
    if(childItem)
        // Pass @childItem as QModelIndex's internal pointer
        return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
    else
        return invalidIndex();
}
```

---

**Getting parent of item:**

```
QModelIndex FilesModel::parent(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return invalidIndex();


    FileItem* childItem = static_cast<FileItem*>(index.internalPointer());

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 
    // @childItem is dandling poiner after call of beginRemoveRows()
    // for root item. See FilesModel::removeRows()
    //

    FileItem* parentItem = childItem->parentItem();

    if(parentItem == nullptr)
        return invalidIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
}
```

### FilesModel::removeRows()

Ok, next impl of `FilesModel::removeRows()` works fine in case, when i try to remove any *file* (sub item of *project*) and any *project* (sub item of *solution*). But, when I'm removing solution item (on of roots element of view), I have the situation, that was described on the beginning of question: **`QAbstractItemModel` calls `parent()` function with `QModelIndex` that returns dangling pointer from `QModelIndex::internalPointer()`**, but I'm passing valid pointers to `createIndex()` and never use explicit deletion of `QModelIndex::internalPointer()`.

---

**Ok, here is items removing:**

```
bool FilesModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent /*= QModelIndex()*/)
{
    Q_ASSERT(count > 0);
    Q_ASSERT(row >= 0);

    if(parent.isValid()) // Child items of @items_
    {
        // This branch works fine
        for(int r = row; r < (row + count); ++r)
        {
            QModelIndex idxRemove = parent.child(r, 0);
            Q_ASSERT(idxRemove.isValid());
            FileItem* fiRemove = static_cast<FileItem*>(idxRemove.internalPointer());
            Q_ASSERT(fiRemove);

            if(idxRemove.child(0, 0).isValid()) // Has childrens
            {
                bool childRemoved = removeRows(0, fiRemove->childCount(), idxRemove);
                Q_ASSERT(childRemoved);
            }
        }

        FileItem* fiParent = static_cast<FileItem*>(parent.internalPointer());
        Q_ASSERT(fiParent->childCount() >= (row + count - 1));

        beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
        int childToRemove = row;
        for(int r = row; r < (row + count); ++r)
            fiParent->removeChild(childToRemove);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }
    else // Removing @items_
    {
        // Here is problem branch

        Q_ASSERT(rowCount() >= (row + count - 1));

        for(int r = row; r < (row + count); ++r)
        {
            FileItem* slnItem = items_.value(r).data();
            bool projectRemoved = removeRows(0, slnItem->childCount(), index(r));
            Q_ASSERT(projectRemoved);
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This call to beginRemoveRows() cause call of parent() function
        // with invalid QModelIndex::internalPointer()
        // 
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1);
        int slnRemove = row;
        for(int r = row; r < (row + count); ++r)
            items_.remove(slnRemove);
        endRemoveRows();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any one know what is the problem ?

I'm working with this model with one, GUI thread. I have Qt 5.4.0 on Windows.
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
`validateItem()` just checks the pointer value to catch the problem with dandling pointer from `QModelView::internalPointer()`

```
void FileItem::validateItem() const
{
    Q_ASSERT((reinterpret_cast<size_t>(this) > 0x1000)
        && "Invalid item");

    for(const FileItemPtr& child : childItems_)
        child->validateItem();
}
```

So, for finding the problem my `FilesModel::parent()` looks like this:

```
QModelIndex FilesModel::parent(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return invalidIndex();


    FileItem* childItem = static_cast<FileItem*>(index.internalPointer());

#if !defined(NDEBUG)
    // Try to understand, if @childItem is OK
    childItem->validateItem();
#endif
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call stack you are showing is indicating that assertion from YOUR CODE is failing, so you should be aware what is the problem!

Check your code in `FileItem::validateItem` line nr 316 to see what is the problem. (Just click proper (second) item in call stack view when crash occurs again)

---

referring to update:

> UPDATE: validateItem() just checks the pointer value to catch the
>   problem with dandling pointer from QModelView::internalPointer()
>
> Q_ASSERT((reinterpret_cast(this) > 0x1000)

WTF? Who told you that this is proper way to detect that? Dangling pointer doesn't mean that pointer has some specific value!

Comment: Yes, I know it. This function was written after a hours of debugging and looking for childItem value. This function is just a reminder that the problem still exists and its relative to problem with internalPointer(). Please, just skip this function. Beleave me - the problem is with internalPointer() and validateItem() is just a wasy to find it

Comment: So, @Marek R, have you any idea ?

Comment: trash this assertion, it is wrong and doesn't give you any extra security! Maybe even trash whole `validateItem` method. There is no simple way to detect dangling pointers. For that you have tools like valgrind.

Comment: can someone explain vote down? Voting down without explanation is a bad practice.